# How to insert raster and other columns using raster2pgsql?

Tags: postgis, postgis-raster

I would like to have a table with a few more columns than just the raster data. Let's say I'd like to have anotherColumn.

I tried

```
raster2pgsql -s 3857 -R -a -k -f public.table.image -q -e -F -X public.table myimage.jpg
```

but I don't think I know how to use the -X option.

Comment: Any follow up on this?